Question about notation in Durrett's book
I have been studying Markov Chains through Rick Durrett's book, more precisely I was focusing on the Markov Property (Theorem 5.2.3 on page 276 of the book available at: https://services.math.duke.edu/~rtd/PTE/PTE5_011119.pdf) in this theorem the author of the book uses the notation $E_{X_{m}}Y$ and he comments that it represents the function $\phi(x) = E_{x}Y $ evaluated at the point $x = X_{m}$ but I don't understand what that means because I don't understand what the notation $E_{x}Y$ represents.
I looked in other parts of the book and consulted some colleagues but we couldn't understand exactly what function $\phi(x)$ defined in this way means.
I guessed it meant $E[Y| X = x]$ but I don't know if that makes sense in this context because in the book it isn't mentioned before as far as I know.
Could anyone try to help me understand?

You should imagine a markov chain as being governed by some law.
$\mathbb{E}_x Y$ means the expectation of $Y$ given that the process was started at state $x$. You correctly identified that it's shorthand for $\mathbb{E}[Y|X_0=x]$. You're conditioning the law of the process to start in state x.
$\mathbb{E}_{X_n} Y$ means the expectation of $Y$ started at the random state $X_n$.
You can think of $Y$ as some statistic of the process. What the theorem says is that the information of past is entirely contained in the information of the present.
The probabilistic intuition is really important when working with Markov chains. The rigorous definitions aren't really important and are a distraction. What's important is understanding how to work with the strong Markov property.

Theorem 5.2.3. The Markov property. Let $Y: \Omega_o \rightarrow \mathbf{R}$ be bounded and measurable.
$$
\mathbb{E}_\mu\left(Y \circ \theta_m \mid \mathscr{F}_m\right)=\mathbb{E}_{X_m} Y
$$


Probability is a mathematical discipline with aims akin to those, for example, of geometry or analytical mechanics. In each field we must carefully distinguish three aspects of the theory: (a) the formal logical content, $(b)$ the intuitive background, $(c)$ the applications. The character, and the charm, of the whole structure cannot be appreciated without considering all three aspects in their proper relation. - Feller


Thank you very much for the explanation and advice!
